# Change glossary entry to show (name) (see ___ , if exists) (description)

Tags: glossaries

I would like to alter the glossary style to be able to show each entry as:
(name) (see ___, if exists) (description) (page#)

How can I accomplish this? Really appreciate your help in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}    
\usepackage{glossaries}      
\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\newglossaryentry{random variable}
{
  name={random variable},
  description={a variable which can take on multiple values}
}
\newglossaryentry{sample space}
{
  name={sample space},
  description={a set of values that a random variable 
  can take},
 see={random variable}
}

\begin{document}
Something about \gls{random variable} and \gls{sample space}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

The output is then:

[image]

I'd really like to have the "see random variable" before the description.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) It would be useful if you augmented your question by a Minimal Working Example (a minimal but complete running document) showing what packages etc. as well as the issue about which you are asking

Comment: Not sure about your intent, but might it not serve to simply nest `\gls{random variable}` within `sample space`'s definition (if possible)?  Indeed, a simple parenthetical list preceding your definition answers the mail - `description = {(\gls*{random variable}, \gls*{sample}) a set of values that a \gls*{random variable} can take}`, and appears to obviate the whole "See" thing.  Again...if possible.

Comment: Actually @commonhare, the downside to your suggestion is that I get page numbers for the cross-references, which is something I don't want to have. I simply want page numbers to refer to where the \gls call was used in the main text. The one way I can accomplish this is to abandon using \gls altogether for cross-references, simply doing "see \textit{random variable}" in the description. Feels kind of hacky though, so I was wondering if there'd be a better option. Thanks!

Comment: I erroneously supposed `\gls*` suppressed citing as well as linking.  Just imagine:  the package authors thought of all this!  Anyway, somewhere within the package is the code that orders the description and cross-ref list.  I looked, but is opaque to me.  Certain that someone here can identify it though...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\glshyperlink` to cross-reference a term without indexing it. (The hyperlink will only occur if you use the `hyperref` package.) So you could do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}    
\usepackage{glossaries}      
\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\newglossaryentry{random variable}
{
  name={random variable},
  description={a variable which can take on multiple values}
}
\newglossaryentry{sample space}
{
  name={sample space},
  description={(see \glshyperlink{random variable}) a set of values that a random variable 
  can take}
}

\begin{document}
Something about \gls{random variable} and \gls{sample space}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Resulting text]

The `see` key essentially works as a special location, in a similar manner to `\index{sample space|see{random variable}}`, so value of the `see` key isn't easy to access.